# Python with openssl cannot do handshake with normal user account (Linux User)

Tags: python, openssl

I have grabbed the internet but cannot get the answer.
I created a sample cert.py file:

```
import ssl
import traceback

def getCert():
    try:
        m_cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.verisign.com', 443))
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        traceback.print_exc()
        m_cert = ''

    print m_cert
getCert()
```

I tried this with "root" permission and it processed fine without any problem, but when I switch to other normal user account, I've always got the following tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/cert.py", line 10, in getCert
    m_cert = ssl.get_server_certificate(('www.verisign.com', 443))
  File "/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 405, in get_server_certificate
  File "/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 299, in connect
  File "/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 283, in do_handshake
```

I also tried to use "openssl" to run the command, and I've got the same result: root is fine, but normal user fails.

Can anyone give some hints on this?

Thanks

Comment: Post the complete traceback please.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the reason why it fails.
The reason is that the /dev/random is set to be 600 in my system, and openssl tried to access it without permission.

After I modifies /dev/random to 666, the issue fixed.